# Add comment after html closing tab with sublime text

Tags: html, formatting, sublimetext3

I want to know if is possible to add comments to existing html closing tags, for example:

```
<div class="container">
Content
</div>
```

And I want to format it to be like this:

```
<div class="container">
Content
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

With emmet (`.container>{Content}`) I will have to rewrite all my code to get the comments, so it's possible to add closing comment with sublime text 3 to an existing html code instead to rewrite it again using emmet?

Comment: If you're using proper indentation in your HTML you shouldn't have to label which div you're closing, because it will be obvious from the indentation. Get into the habit *now* of writing readable code, and it will become second-nature to you. Use HTML prettify plugins to indent your existing code properly, and always properly indent any new code you write.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the end of your post regarding emmet, but adding a comment after the HTML closing tag should be fine as any comments in an HTML file are ignored by the browser regardless of where they are placed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you actually **read** the whole question? OP is not asking about whether HTML comments are legal or not. They're trying to programmatically fill in the contents of the comment with the class id(s) of the element they are closing.

Comment: Yes, I did READ the whole question (thank you for the completely unnecessary patronisation, why would you do such a thing when I was just trying to help?). I did not realise that's what he wanted from the question at all. I would suggest the author of the question makes himself a little clearer.